# How to calculate the expectation for the following cost function

Tags: expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X_2$ and $X_3$ be two non-negative independent exponentially distributed random variables with a parameter $\lambda$.

Assume I have the following cost function:

$$W(X_2) = \begin{cases}  X_2+X_3 , \space \space \space \space  X_2 < 10 \space AND \space X_3<10,\\ 0, \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space\space \space\space\space\space  otherwise 
  \end{cases} $$

Now I want to calculate the expectation of $W$. However, I'm confused if I need to use double integration like this:

$$E[W] = \int\int (x_2+x_3)\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x_2} e^{-\lambda x_3}dx_2dx_3,$$

Where the limits of this double integral from $0$ to $10$. Or just saying:

$$E[W] = E[X_2]+E[X_3]$$ 
where $$ E[X_i] = \int x_i \lambda e^{-\lambda x_i } dx_i$$

and the integration from $0$ to $10$

Comment: The double integral looks right (except the fact that you have written $x_3$ twice in the density and the differential), but what do you plan to replace $c$ with? More importantly, you have not mentioned anything about the independence of $X_2$ and  $X_3$.

Comment: Well, where does $X_1$ come into play?

Comment: @StubbornAtom see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$
W=(X_2+X_3)\mathbb 1_{\{X_2<10\}}\mathbb 1_{\{X_3<10\}} = X_2 \mathbb 1_{\{X_2<10\}}\mathbb 1_{\{X_3<10\}} + X_3\mathbb 1_{\{X_2<10\}}\mathbb 1_{\{X_3<10\}} 
$$
and $X_2,X_3$ are independent, you can split it into
$$
\mathbb E[W] = \mathbb E[X_2; X_2<10]\mathbb P(X_3<10)+\mathbb E[X_3; X_3<10]\mathbb P(X_2<10)
$$
$$
=2\left(1-e^{-10\lambda}\right)\int_0^{10} x \lambda e^{-\lambda x } dx 
$$
Note that 
$$
\mathbb E[W] \neq \mathbb E[X_2; X_2<10]+\mathbb E[X_3; X_3<10].
$$
Double integral give the right answer too.